# Tunslip deactivates WiFi in raspberry pi B+ board

Tags: linux, wifi, raspberry-pi, tunneling, node.js

I'm using Contiki operating system with Cooja to simulate a sensor node network. And I'm trying to capture the ip packets it's sending in a Raspberry Pi B+ board (through USB) using tunslip6 and a CoAPclient I wrote using nodejs. I'm trying to send these CoAP messages through wifi to another machine. But what I've seen is, everytime I initiate tunslip, my WiFi gets disabled of sorts. There's no power going to the wifi module, and I have to use ifdown and ifup again to restart the module. This happens everytime I start tunslip and it begins listening for messages.

Why would my WiFi connection go for a toss when I start Tunslip? Is this because I'm using it to capture the data from the border router through USB? Is there some power to the WiFi port that is being blocked when Tunslip is started? I have no idea how to fix this either. A quick patch would be to write a script which continuously monitors if the WiFi goes down, and repeatedly tries to bring it back up until it succeeds. But this is a shaky duct-tape approach and I want to understand the real reason why I'm facing this issue too.

I hope I was clear. Thanks!